# PHP session_name not working

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am using this script, setting the session name with `session_name`:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_name ("my_cookie");
session_start();
...
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

however, in the browser opening the site, I'm still seeing the cookie name `osCsid`. 
What am I missing?
How do I set the session name properly?

--EDIT--

here is the full script:

```
<?php
  session_name ("MyCookie");
  session_start();
  $UA = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $REF = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $IP =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $GUID = session_id();
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  //echo $UA;
  //echo $REF;
  //echo $IP;
  //echo $GUID;
  echo ("python ../header_sender.py -u '$UA' -r '$REF' -i '$IP' -c '$GUID' -p '$actual_link' 2>&1");
  echo exec("python /var/www/html/oscommerce-2.3.3.4/header_sender.py -u '$UA' -r '$REF' -i '$IP' -c '$GUID' -p '$actual_link' 2>&1");
  ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have it in `ob_*` ?

Comment: @Rizier123  - I was under the impression that setting the session should happen before sending output to the browser. Should I remove it?

Comment: Remove it and it will work! :D

Comment: Please show us your entire script. Also did you try these 2 lines in a separated script?

Comment: @Rizier123 - added the full script. Also yes I tried omitting everything but those two lines, still did not change the name...

Comment: You said you still see the cookie: `osCsid` maybe this is from earlier test's? Did you destroyed your session and all your cookies to test it ?

Comment: I deleted the cookie from the browser. It is happily regenerated as `osCsid` every time...

Comment: [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) is disabled?

Comment: @Laxus - yup. from the ini file: `session.auto_start = 0`

Comment: Try adding `print_r(headers_list());` at the bottom of your code and see the output. Maybe the cookie is set with the secure flag?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue:

The problem wat that oscommerce was overriding the session, killing my cookie and replacing it with `osCsid` [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123056/remove-oscsid-id-from-url-in-oscommerce) had the answer.

Many Thanks to Rizier and Laxus for trying to help me out...